# Adding drop shadow to custom UITableCellView not working

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

So I have a custom UITableCellView that has a bunch of subviews inside of it. I'm trying to add a drop shadow to this cell -

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [self.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [self.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
    [self.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
    [self.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(4.0, 4.0)];
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;


}
```

So I overrode the draw rect method to do so - but this isn't working.

How should I add a drop shadow to each cell?

Comment: try self.contentview.layer

Comment: Why `drawRect:`? Overriding this method is costly operation ? Try whats mentioned in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546880/iphone-uitableviewcell-layer-shadow . Hope it helps!

Comment: wait - so what would I override?

Comment: the contentview thing worked - but now the shadow is only on one side - can I make it all the way around?

Comment: drop shadow will shows on outside bounds in view,UITableCellView outside bounds not shown in UITableView

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 0);
cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = .25;


CGRect shadowFrame = cell.layer.bounds;
CGPathRef shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shadowFrame].CGPath;
cell.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

since u hav custom cell then u can add shadow like this,

```
   //this is in custom cell assume u hav "CustomCell" class
   //in CustomCell.m 

  - (void)layoutSubviews
   {
       [super layoutSubviews];

       //add shadow properties by using layers 
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8f; //self is the custom cell 
        self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor; //set the shadow color

       // .. other layer properties and effects u want

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[self layer] setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [[self layer] setShadowOpacity:0.8f];
    [[self layer] setShadowRadius:3.0f];
    [[self layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(4.0f, 4.0f)];
    [[self layer] setShouldRasterize:YES];
    [[self layer] setRasterizationScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
}
```