# Get shadow for custom tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, shadow

I have a UITableView in UIViewController. I have multiple sections with only one row. How can i get shadow for cell like in next picture?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the shadow to be created outside of the bounds;

[cell.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];

and then you need to set

```
[cell.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
[cell.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
[cell.layer setShadowRadius:8.0];
[cell.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];

return cell;
```

and if not success you can also try this solution.

[iPhone UITableViewCell layer shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546880/iphone-uitableviewcell-layer-shadow)

or you can also refer this tutorial for your reference.

[Fun shadow effects using custom CALayer shadowPaths](http://nachbaur.com/blog/fun-shadow-effects-using-custom-calayer-shadowpaths)