# Label shadow not working in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikit, core-graphics

I tried to give a shadow to label text but it does not shown.

**My code**

```
private func drawValueLabel() {

    valueLabel.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    valueLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 15.0, height: 15.0)
    valueLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
    valueLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    valueLabel.layer.masksToBounds = false
    valueLabel.clipsToBounds = false
    valueLabel.layer.shouldRasterize = true

    valueLabel.drawText(in: self.bounds)

}
```

**Help me to show shadow**

**Thanks**

Comment: your code is fine and correct

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367129/uitableviewcell-shadows/44367371#44367371

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this UIView extension for add shadow. With this extension you can add shadow from storyboard.

```
extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable var shadow: Bool {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity > 0.0
        }
        set {
            if newValue == true {
                self.addShadow()
            }
        }
    }

    func addShadow(shadowColor: CGColor = UIColor.black.cgColor,
                   shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 2.0),
                   shadowOpacity: Float = 0.4,
                   shadowRadius: CGFloat = 3.0) {
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor
        layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
        layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine for me. Try giving some smaller offset so that you would be able to see it like

```
label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 3.0, height: 3.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this -
    `label.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    label.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    label.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
    label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)`